# Rails and Sprockets require file from parent folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sprockets

I'm using `Sprockets` and I want to add require from parent folder into my `application.js`, 
So I've tried this :

```
//= require ../plugins/adminlte/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap
```

but it doesn't work I get

> Sprockets::FileNotFound

this is the path of file I want to import :

```
-lib/assets/plugins/adminlte/plugins/dataTables.bootstrap.js
```

Comment: Did you solve this problem? It would be helpful to have an update as I'm having the same trouble.

Answer (score 1):

My solution to the same problem was to explicitly add the directory to the assets path in `application.rb`:

```
  class Application < Rails::Application
      # Initialize configuration defaults for originally generated Rails version.
      config.load_defaults 5.2
      config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app/assets/the_folder')
```

I could then import the required file without having to reference the folder:

```
 *
 *= require 'the_asset.scss'
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

Any folder created directly under assets will be added to the load paths. So you just have to use `//=require adminlte/plugins/dataTables.bootstrap.js`

Comment: No doesn't work, also read this :



`// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.`